# how do I get out of this auth error loop when trying to run a pipeline?

Tags: azure

I've created a new Pipeline.  When I Run the pipeline, the pipeline fails with an error and displays the error in a pink box at the bottom of the page:

> There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid.
> Job Job: Step AzureWebApp input azureSubscription references service
> connection 88587ed4-30db-41a8-b05f-4b816b7d6c7a which could not be
> found. The service connection does not exist or has not been
> authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to
> [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

The pink error box has an "Authorize resources" button on the right.  When I click that button the webpage displays a success message and the button text changes to "Resources authorized"

So then I click the "Rerun failed jobs" button at the top of the page and then the webpage displays the following message at the top of the page:

> "No plan found for identifier cd3d838c-7810-427a-8a30-0385eea2d7de."

Any idea what the root cause might be here or what I need to do in order to get out of this weird loop so I can successfully run this pipeline to completion?